# Regex not detects the field is null or have white space

Tags: c#, regex

I am using regex in c# to validate the field(not null or white space), means field must contains some value even single character.
I have to use **REGEX** its mandatory due to some reason.
my regex is

> ^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$

Comment: A regex cannot detect *null*. If you mean there must be at least 1 non-whitespace, use `@"\S"` or - if you need to match the whole string, `^\s*\S.*$` or `^\s*\S[\s\S]*$` or `(?s)^\s*\S.*$`. Please clarify what you are doing.

Comment: Why not use `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(string s)`?

Comment: I have to use regex.

Comment: @UzairXlade You should explain the use case. Why "have to"?

Comment: telling us in your question that is is mandatory for some reason doesnt really help us to understand why the answer we give MUST have a regex on it

Comment: i am making dynamic view, i set regex in database and it populate with the field, thats why, i have to use regex.

Comment: @ Wiktor Stribiżew: i mean there should be one charter in value, but not <space>.

Comment: Thats exactly what Wiktor gave you in his 1rst comment with [`\S`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-language-quick-reference) please provide a exmeple a string where this one fail

Comment: @UzairXlade Cool, so one of my patterns should work for you.

Answer (score 1):

There is an extension method to `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace`. What you want to achieve is more or less exactly what it does. Please see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorwhitespace(v=vs.110).aspx)

**Example:**

```
string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(string.Empty); // returns true
string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(null); // returns true
string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace("   "); // returns true
string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace("ABC"); // returns false
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you should be checking is its null, empty or whitespace

```
var str = "";
if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(str) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(str))
{
    // then do something here
}
```

Comment: Please check the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorwhitespace(v=vs.110).aspx) - *"true if the value parameter is **null** or **String.Empty**, or if value consists **exclusively of white-space characters**."*. `IsNullOrEmpty` is redundant.

Comment: I was just looking at your example thinking it was more elegant than what I had given. I typically just use `IsNullOrEmpty` and rarely consider `IsNullOrWhiteSpace` which is why I marked an upvote on it.